# Want to filter more then 10 million numbers on Telegram

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

I need a little help. I have more then 10 millions number and i want to filter those contacts on telegram like which number exist on telegram or not.
I have search a lot but not get any method which fulfil my needs.

I have checked IsphoneRegistered or CheckPhone it return true in every request.

Answer (score 1):

Telethon API > [ImportContactsRequest](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/import_contacts.html)

With Telethon API [ImportContactsRequest](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/import_contacts.html) you can check if the given phone exists on Telegram. If found it will return Array with user details otherwise it will return emtpy array.

Note: As of today, you can only get telegram_id of the user, first_name, last_name are returned null even if they exist.

Comment: Thanks brother, problem is that it only filter first 150 numbers after 150 number it return empty array either number exist or not